# checking if the values in one column are in order for the ID field using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to choose one record per ID, based on the values in the sort field.
if there is a gap of more than 1 in the Sort filed I would want to assign the maximum sort value for that ID field. If the sort field is in order (eg for ID B the sort filed is 9,10, 11,12)
I would like to choose the minimum value for the ID.

[image: below is the input and required output]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVLsx.png)

Comment: Have a look at `FIRST_VALUE`/`LAST_VALUE`.

Comment: Also, please don't use images for sample data. Data is text, and so should be posted as text. Well formatted tables or DDL and DML statements are the best methods.

Comment: I found First_value and last_value very useful .. But in this case how do I find out the sort field is in order like (11,10,9,8,7) and there is no gap like (11, 9,8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.ID, MIN(i.sort) as sort
FROM input as i
INNER JOIN 
 (
  Select ID, MAX(diff) as gap
  FROM
   (
    SELECT ID, Sort, Rank, 
     LEAD(sort) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sort desc) as lead, 
     ABS(sort - LEAD(sort) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sort desc)) as diff 
    FROM input
   ) as a
  WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ID) as s
ON i.ID=s.ID
WHERE s.gap=1 
GROUP BY i.ID

UNION

SELECT i.ID, MAX(i.sort) as sort
FROM input as i
INNER JOIN 
 (
  Select ID, MAX(diff) as gap
  FROM
   (
    SELECT ID, Sort, Rank, 
     LEAD(sort) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sort desc) as lead, 
     ABS(sort - LEAD(sort) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sort desc)) as diff 
    FROM input
   ) as a
  WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ID) as s
ON i.ID=s.ID
WHERE s.gap<>1 
GROUP BY i.ID
```

I have used multiple sub-query. You can use CTE or create intermediate tables if required.

*db<>fiddle* link [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c03aa41b26dee1b2e94ed73e3b40c0b)

Comment: Thank you. will try this..